# powershell stop process using 45% cpu

Tags: powershell, process

Does anyone know how to stop a process that is hung at around 45% CPU usage using powershell.

I run into having to do this alot manually and would like to:

First develop a script that can find the process by name (in this case it's a process called dfileman.exe used by an application running on a Windows 2003 server), check to see if it's stuck at equal to or greater than 45% CPU usage for more than 5 minutes and stop it if it meets the criteria. The application will start a new process the next time it needs it so I'm not worried about restarting it.

Second, use MS SCOM to monitor the dfileman.exe process, run the above script whenever it gets hung and send me an email whenever the script was run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Even if it's just helping me with the script.

What I have so far is:

```
$ProcessName = "defilman.exe"

$PSEmailServer = "smtp.company.com"


foreach ($proc in (Get-WmiObject  Win32_Processor)){
    if($proc.numberofcores -eq $null){
        $cores++
    }else{
        $cores = $cores + $proc.numberofcores
    }
} 
$cpuusage = [Math]::round(((((Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName)\% Processor Time" -MaxSamples 2).Countersamples)[0].CookedValue)/$cores),2)

if ($cpuusage -gt 45)

Send-MailMessage -To "Me (myaddress)" -From "Me (myaddress)" -Subject "DFileMan Process Hung" -body "An instance of $ProcessName on Server has reached a CPU Percentage of $cpuusage %. Please Kill Process Immediately"

else
Exit
```

Comment: Can you paste the script you have?

Comment: I formatted your script so it's a little easier to read. Thanks for adding that. Hopefully @Bonifacio2, or whoever it was that downvoted you will come back and remove the downvote since you did as asked. That script (though missing some things like `{ }` for your last If/Than/Else statement) doesn't even try to stop the process. What have you done to actually try and stop the process? What errors are you getting?

Comment: It wasn't me, @TheMadTechnician. :)

Comment: Thanks! Once I can get this cleared, I would then adjust to remove the process and email me with a notification stating that the process was stopped.  I'm getting this error with the current script.     

  
>Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
At C:\dfileman.ps1:17 char:1
+  <<<< Send-MailMessage -To "Me (me@company.com)" -From "Me (me@company.com)" -Subject "DFileMan Process Hung" -body "An instance of $ProcessName on 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlock  @TheMadTechnician

Comment: So an If statement is written like this: `If(test){code to run if test passes}` right now you are missing the `{ }` from that. Also, you can remove the Else and Exit from the end of your script. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  This info fixed it.  Much appreciated! It's almost always syntax where an issue lies.  @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Added that as an answer so you can mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a custom script, take a look at Performance Monitor. It has [built-in functionality](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324752) for taking actions when a counter stays long enough on specific a value.

After Perfmon has detected that the app is using too much CPU, you can use Powershell or whatever to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

So an If statement is written like this: If(test){code to run if test passes} right now you are missing the { } from that. Corrected code:

```
if ($cpuusage -gt 45){
    Send-MailMessage -To "Me (myaddress)" -From "Me (myaddress)" -Subject "DFileMan Process Hung" -body "An instance of $ProcessName on Server has reached a CPU Percentage of $cpuusage %. Please Kill Process Immediately"
}
```